# HttpClient get Request with Bearer Token doesn't work from Angular but works fine with Postman

Tags: angular, httpclient, bearer-token, get-request

So I want to send a `HttpClient` get Request From Angular with `Bearer Token`.
The API Call works fine with Postman using `Bearer` token but for some reason it returns `error code 500` when sent from Angular.
This is my service code :

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
let token = localStorage.token
console.log(token)
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', "Bearer " + token);
console.log(httpHeaders)
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/user/getCurrentUser`, {headers : httpHeaders});
```

}

It is not a CORS issue, seeing as I already checked with Allow-CORS Chrome extension, also, this is my Request Filter from server side:

```
   @Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RequestFilter implements Filter{
    
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain){
        
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req; 
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res; 
        
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, x-auth-token");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Controll-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        
        if(!request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")){
            
            try{                              
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT,GET, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, x-auth-token, authorization, content-type, access-control-request-headers, access-control-request-method, accept, origin,");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }
    
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig){}

    public void destroy(){}
}
```

So what is the problem here ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  What language/framework are you running on the server?

Comment: Try it by keeping "A" to lowercase of Authorization. it worked for me.

Comment: @cjd82187 this is the error I am getting : Http failure response for http://localhost:8888/user/getCurrentUser: 500 OK
I'm running spring boot for the server

Comment: @SavanPadaliya Already tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: why guess ? compare your postman request with the request on the chrome devtools/network tab. if it's the same request, it will produce the same response.

Comment: @Stavm Postman will not match what chrome does, as Postman is not a browser and will not have CORS related issues.  But, it is a good test to check.  If it works in Postman but not in your browser its extremely likely a CORS Issue

Comment: @Clover you should debug your server and see where the error is coming from on the server if it doesn't send that info to the client.  I don't know anything about "Allow-CORS Chrome extension", but if your request works in Postman but not Chrome and the request and headers are the same, its probably a CORS issue.

Comment: I think that error code 500 is "Internal Server Error", indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request, it's not about Authorization